# Uncheck other checkboxes when a checkbox is enabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following checboxes:
https://puu.sh/ITv7l/a12f829ee3.png which are assigned to the following script:

```
// Sort by ETH %
function onEdit3(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != '% Changes') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 11) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == 'TRUE') sort_by_ETH(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == 'FALSE') unsort(e);
}

function sort_by_ETH(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 6, ascending: false});
}

function unsort(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}

// Sort by GODS %
function onEdit4(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != '% Changes') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 11) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.value == 'TRUE') sort_by_GODS(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 3 && e.value == 'FALSE') unsort(e);
}

function sort_by_GODS(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 7, ascending: false});
}

function unsort(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}

// Sort by God
function onEdit5(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != '% Changes') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 11) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 4 && e.value == 'TRUE') sort_by_God(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 4 && e.value == 'FALSE') unsort(e);
}

function sort_by_God(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}

function unsort(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}

// Sort by Set
function onEdit6(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != '% Changes') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 11) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value == 'TRUE') sort_by_Set(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value == 'FALSE') unsort(e);
}

function sort_by_Set(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
}

function unsort(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}

// Sort by Rarity
function onEdit7(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != '% Changes') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 11) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart == 6 && e.value == 'TRUE') sort_by_Rarity(e);
  if (e.range.rowStart == 6 && e.value == 'FALSE') unsort(e);
}

function sort_by_Rarity(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 4, ascending: true});
}

function unsort(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate()
  .sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
}
```

I want to:

> 1. Once a checkbox is checked, all rest checkboxes to become unchecked. For example if K2 is checked, then make K3, K4, K5, K6 unchecked.
> 2. Improve script, because right now it has many loops, for example when a checkbox is unchecked it always does the same unsort function.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I give you an easy example of how this can achieve it:

Imagine that you have this sheet:

[image: Sheet Example]

What is the trick?

- Extract the range of the [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- Limit the [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) event to only listen to the range of the checkboxes.
- Set all the values to false and set the changed checkbox to true.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const { range: { columnStart, rowStart, rowEnd }, value } = e
  /* Updated to prevent FALSE to run the function */
  if (value === "FALSE") return;
  /* Range of the checkboxes */
  const checkRowStart = 1
  const checkRowEnd = 5
  const checkColumn = 2 // Correspond to B
  /* Check only checkboxes in the desired range */
  if (columnStart === checkColumn && checkRowStart <= rowStart && checkRowEnd >= rowEnd) {
    /* Set all to false */
    for (let i = 0; i < checkRowEnd; i++) {
      ss.getRange(i + checkRowStart, checkColumn).setValue(false)
    }
    /* Set the desired one to true */
    ss.getRange(rowStart, columnStart).setValue(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply however that's not what im looking for!

Comment: The script does exactly this `Once a checkbox is checked, all rest checkboxes to become unchecked.`. So, can you give a more precise explanation on what are you looking for?

Comment: The problem with your script is that you can't disable all checkboxes, it automatically enables a checkbox and keeps it checked no matter what.

Comment: Just add `if (e.value == 'FALSE') return;` after the `if ...` line if you want to disable the function in case the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Updated the question to add the line suggested by [Yuri Khristich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14265469/yuri-khristich)