# onEdit checkbox then IMPORTRANGE

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, eventtrigger

I'm trying to combine a onEdit script with an import range script, I tried using "if" to check if there's a single TRUE checkbox on the selected range but the import range part does not work only the checkbox part.
I need to import only after a single TRUE checkbox is enabled on column 7 otherwise the other spreadsheet glitches.

Source for the checkbox validation script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71798583/18249133

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const { range: { columnStart, rowStart, rowEnd }, value } = e
  if (value === "FALSE") return;
  const checkRowStart = 4
  const checkRowEnd = 200
  const checkColumn = 7
  if (columnStart === checkColumn && checkRowStart <= rowStart && checkRowEnd >= rowEnd) {
    for (let i = 0; i < checkRowEnd; i++) {
      ss.getRange(i + checkRowStart, checkColumn).setValue(false)
    }
    ss.getRange(rowStart, columnStart).setValue(true)
  }
}
```

Import range script

```
function import(){
  importRange(    
    "SPREADSHEET_ID",
    "SHEET NAME + RANGE",
    "SPREADSHEET_ID",
    "SHEET NAME + RANGE",
    );
};

function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart) {

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);

};
```

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand the relationship between your question and "onEdit" and "import" shown in your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Sure! =)

In the following image example (https://prnt.sc/Ykf2KYXhZe-E), you can see that when I press the checkbox a "Download" appears sent from another spreadsheet. The problem is since I'm connecting to an API to request links if a user press more than one checkbox he will send more than one request for the API producing a timeout.

So to make sure he requests only one URL I need the script to uncheck when he checks for another validation and only import to the other spreadsheet when there's only one data validation as TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.